# SQL Query To Retrieve Orders Only Containing Specific Products

Tags: sql

Suppose I have these tables:

Customer(CustomerID as PK), Order(OrderID as PK, CustomerID as FK), OrderDetails(OrderDetalisID as PK, OrderID as PK, ProductID as PK), Products(ProductID as PK, CategoryID as FK) and Category(CategoryID as PK).

How can I for instance only retrieve all orders that contain products from category 1 and two exclusively?

EDIT: This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Order.Order_ID, Order.Order_Total, Customer.CustomerName
FROM Orders
JOIN Customers on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
JOIN Products on OrderDetails.ProductID = Products.ProductID
WHERE Products.ProductID IN ( SELECT Products.ProductID FROM PRODUCTS
JOIN Category on Products.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
WHERE Category.CategoryID = 1 OR Category.CategoryID = 2);
```

Comment: What you have tried and is the issue you are facing?

Comment: Mysql and sqlite are two defferent db products, which one do you use?

Comment: I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can get order Ids for products in categories 1 and 2 by using a join, and then you can get all the orders with ids from the resulted list:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Order
WHERE OrderID IN (
  SELECT OD.OrderId
  FROM OrderDetails OD
    INNER JOIN Products P
      ON OD.ProductID = P.ProductID 
  WHERE P.CategoryID IN (1, 2)
)
```

Comment: I normally try to do it but this one seemed pretty straightforward.. anyway added what I could

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve the orders, you can do it like this

```
select distinct od.OrderId
from OrderDetails od
  join Products p
      on od.ProductId=p.ProductId
where p.CategoryId in (1,2)
```

You must use the `distinct` clause because some orders could have products for both categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` to select order for which both 1 and 2 categories exist.

```
select * from order 
where exists 
          (
           select 1 from orderdetails od inner join products p on 
           od.productid=p.productid 
           where p.categoryid in (1,2) and od.orderid=o.orderid
           group by orderid 
           having count(distinct categoryid)=2
          )
```